# Reference request: Abelianization/ Commutator subgroup of $U_n(R)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, matrices, group-theory, reference-request

I'm looking for a **reference** for the following statement:

Let $R$ be a (commutative) ring with 1 and $U_n(R)\subset GL_n(R)$ the subgroup of upper triangular matrices with only 1 on the diagonal. Then
$$U_n(R)^{ab} \cong R^{n-1} $$
or equivalently the commutator subgroup $[U_n(R),U_n(R)]$ is the subgroup of $U_n(R)$ with $0$ on the first superdiagonal.

This is usually formulated as an exercises in some books, the proof uses that $U_n(R)$ is generated by certain elementary matrices.